# Azure Pipeline Step - Trigger Databricks Job

Tags: azure-pipelines, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

I am trying to trigger a databricks job in a pipeline step where I use the job id passed as a variable from the previous step.

This is how I create the job id and pass it as a variable:

```
- script: |
    job_id=$(databricks jobs create --json '{"name": "test", "existing_cluster_id" : "'"$(db_clusterid)"'", "notebook_task ": {"notebook_path": "'"$(nbpath)"'"}}')
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=db_job_id;]'"$job_id"'"
  env:
    DB_HOST: $(db_host)
    DB_TOKEN: $(db_token)
  displayName: 'Create Job'
```

When I echo the variable in the next step it looks as expected:

```
- script: |
    echo $DB_JOB_ID
  env:
    DB_JOB_ID: $(db_job_id)
    DB_HOST: $(db_host)
    DB_TOKEN: $(db_token)
  displayName: 'Echo Job ID'
```

Output from echo:

```
'{ "job_id": 123 }'
```

However, when I try to run the job as follows:

```
- script: |
    databricks jobs run-now --job-id $DB_JOB_ID
  env:
    DB_JOB_ID: $(db_job_id)
    DB_HOST: $(db_host)
    DB_TOKEN: $(db_token)
  displayName: 'Run Job'
```

The following error message arises:

```
Error: Got unexpected extra arguments ("job_id": 123}')
```

Instead of providing  `$DB_JOB_ID` I also tried `"$DB_JOB_ID"` and `"'"$DB_JOB_ID"'"` which did not work either.

What would be the correct statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're putting the whole JSON that is returned, while the `run-now` is requiring only job ID that is number.  You can replace the `--job-id $DB_JOB_ID` with `--job-id $(echo $DB_JOB_ID||sed -e 's|^.*:[ ]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)[ ]*.*$|\1|')` - it will extract only required job ID.

P.S. Instead of the `databricks jobs create` as one step and then running `databricks jobs run-now`, it's better to use `databricks jobs submit` (or use [Run Submit REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-submit)) - it just will run the job without creating it.

You can also look onto the [dbx package](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) developed inside Databricks - it may simplify the way how do you schedule jobs, wait for results, etc.